# DVD to x265 mp4 Remove Duplicate Frames with correct Framerate

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg

I'm using [FFmepg](https://ffmpeg.org) to re-encode an `m2v` video to `mp4` `x265`.

The source video is an NTSC DVD with framerate `29.97`.

**VLC** and **Windows** properties both give `29.97`, but **FFprobe** says `r_frame_rate` is `59.94`.

**FFprobe file properties:**

```
codec_name=mpeg2video
codec_time_base=1001/30000
r_frame_rate=60000/1001
avg_frame_rate=30000/1001
```

---

## Problem

Using no FFmpeg framerate options causes the new `mp4`'s framerate to be `59.94`.

*With* framerate options it ends up at `29.97` like the source.

```
-x265-params "fps=30000/1001" 
-framerate 30000/1001 
-r 30000/1001
```

#### Removing Duplicates Frames

I got a warning `More than 1000 frames duplicated`, probably because of the `60000/1001` to `30000/1001` conversion. Though it can't really be `59.94 fps` because the source is an NTSC DVD.

**vsync**

`-vsync 0` removed the duplicate frames but caused the video to be `23.94 fps`.

**mpdecimate**

`-vf "mpdecimate, fps=30000/1001"`

Removed duplicate frames and gave the correct `29.97 fps` but looks choppier. Maybe those duplicate frames were needed?

---

### FFmpeg Settings

```
ffmpeg -y 

-fflags +genpts 

-i input.m2v

-c:v libx265 
-preset medium -x265-params "crf=20:rc-lookahead=18:fps=30000/1001"
-pix_fmt yuv420p 
-tune grain -profile:v main -level 4.1 

-copyts 
-avoid_negative_ts make_zero 

-vf "mpdecimate, fps=30000/1001"

-threads 0

output.mp4
```

---

## Questions

What is the correct way to be converting this to `x265` `mp4` while preserving the original framerate?

Is the DVD source framerate `29.97` or `59.94`?

Should I have to be removing duplicate frames and is it damaging the video?

Comment: Has the footage been deinterlaced? If no, does ffmpeg show it as interlaced?

Comment: @Gyan I believe the source is progressive, there are no interlace lines in the footage. How can I tell if it is interlaced using ffprobe or ffmpeg?

Comment: `ffprobe in.m2v -show_entries frame=pkt_pts_time,interlaced_frame -select_streams v -of compact=p=0 -v 0`

Comment: @Gyan It says `field_order=progressive` and loops through times and says `1pkt_pts_time=81.281200|interlaced_frame=0`.

Comment: And `ffprobe in.m2v -fpsprobesize 100 -show_entries stream=r_frame_rate,avg_frame_rate -select_streams v -of compact=p=0 -v 0`?

Comment: @Gyan That gives `r_frame_rate=60000/1001|avg_frame_rate=30000/1001`. I believe the command you gave before shows that it's progressive and not interlaced.

Comment: Your input will have some frames with duration 1001/60000 s and hence the r_frame_rate, which ffmpeg uses to set output rate. Manual override is your workaround.

Comment: @Gyan Why is the `r_frame_rate` on the dvd set to `60000/1001` when the actual framerate is `29.97`? What is the best way to manually override it?

Comment: ffmpeg sets r_frame_rate to the inverse of the frame with the smallest duration that it finds during stream probe. Input `-framerate ` is advisable.

Comment: @Gyan I removed `mpdecimate` and added `-framerate 30000/1001` before the `-i` input. It seems to have fixed the problem, no duplicate frames warning, and mp4 is `29.97 fps`. Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: For m2v input, yes.

Comment: @Gyan I have another question here about FFmpeg Framerate options if you'd like to take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51143100/6806643