# Framerate vs r vs Filter fps

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to better understand FFmpeg framerate.

**Example:** If I wanted to convert a `30 fps` video to `23.976 fps`.

---

### What are the differences between:

Option
`-framerate 24000/1001`

Option
`-r 24000/1001`

Filter
`-vf "fps=24000/1001"`

x265 params
`-x265-params "fps=24000/1001"`

---

### What I've read is:

`-framerate` is image sequence fps (input video fps?)

`-vf "fps="` is encoding fps

`-r` is output fps

However I don't know if that is correct, or if it changes depending on what order you place them in the options.

---

### Questions

1. `-x265-params "fps="` Is it required use it's own fps param? Can it not use default options?
2. Should multiple Options, Filters ,and Params be combined, or should you only use one?
3. Input/Output Framerate

   https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Video-Options

   `-r[:stream_specifier] fps (input/output,per-stream)`

   `If in doubt use -framerate instead of the input option -r.`

   Is `-r` input or output? How do you specify, by putting before or after the `-i`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`-framerate` is an input per-file option. It is meant for input formats which don't have  a framerate or PTS defined, image sequences being an example.

`-r` can be either an input or output option. As an input option, it retimes input frames at that rate. As an output option, it will duplicate or drop frames to achieve the given rate (note that it won't duplicate frames if output format accepts variable frame rate). Output `r` is the 'encoding rate' as well. If it is not specified, it is inherited from the input rate, whether that's manually set or altered or an inherent property of the stream.

`fps` filter allows one to alter a stream's framerate while filtering by dropping or duplicating frames to achieve the given rate. It overrides the input stream rate. Its main use is to manipulate a stream before combining it with other streams, or before filtering it further.

`-x265-params fps` is a private property of the x265 encoder. Its main purpose is to signal a duration for each frame for the purposes of rate-control. Encoders like x264/5 devote more bits to frames that are shown for longer. It does not actually alter framerate or number of frames or frame duration.

Comment: Thanks. I'm building a Script Generator for FFmpeg. If you want to contribute any ideas or corrections for it let me know. https://github.com/MattMcManis/Axiom

Comment: How do I set a maximum frame rate?

Comment: So is your answer implying that if I make a slideshow from three images and set "-r 3" that it will duplicate the each of the three images in order to hold each image for 3 seconds?

Comment: To add, the `framerate` [_filter_](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#framerate) `-v:f framerate` (not the option) _does_ convert frame rate, with linear frame interpolation.

Comment: From the ffmpeg page: 

`ffmpeg [global_options] {[input_file_options] -i input_url} ... {[output_file_options] output_url} ...`

So whether an option is for input or output depends on whether you specify it before -i or after inputs and before ouput file

Comment: Does changing the framerate with fps somehow make the ending video play faster? I had an original video with a framerate of 60 then used fps=fps=30 to create a small animation and reduce the possible output size, but I have a feeling that the animation plays slightly faster than the original movie...